# ItemRenderer shows through ItemEditor

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

On an mx:datagrid, I use custom itemrenderer and itemeditor.
When cell is on edit mode, Itemeditor separator is visible inside itemeditor.

So it isn't beautiful, and difficult to read what you write.

On itemEditor, I try to use contentBackgroundColor and overriding updateDisplayList

See below all code for itemEditor

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                          focusEnabled="true"

                          creationComplete="mxdatagriditemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                          focusIn="mxdatagriditemrenderer1_focusInHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import fr.util.UtilString;

            import mx.controls.DataGrid;
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
            import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.core.UITextField;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            public var htmlModif:String;
            public var beginIndex:int;
            public var endIndex:int;

            protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF); // white
                graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                graphics.endFill();

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }

            override public function validateProperties():void
            {
                super.validateProperties();
                if (listData)
                {
                    var dg:DataGrid = DataGrid(listData.owner);

                    var column:DataGridColumn = dg.columns[listData.columnIndex];

                    var htmlText:UITextField = lblData.htmlText as UITextField;

                }


            }

            protected function lblData_focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
            {
                beginIndex = lblData.selectionBeginIndex;
                endIndex= lblData.selectionEndIndex;
            }

            protected function mxdatagriditemrenderer1_focusInHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
            {
                lblData.editable=true;
            }

            protected function mxdatagriditemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                //set cursor postion to end
                lblData.selectionBeginIndex=lblData.htmlText.length;
                lblData.selectionEndIndex=lblData.htmlText.length+1;
                lblData.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,copyGloss_focusInHandler);

                lblData.setFocus();             
            }

            // ajout de terme venant du gloassaire
            protected function copyGloss_focusInHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.copyFromGloss){
                    if(Clipboard.generalClipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT)){ 


                        var textCpb:String = Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT) as String; 


                        var ind:int = new UtilString().calculateHtmlPosition(lblData.htmlText, lblData.selectionBeginIndex);
                        lblData.htmlText = lblData.htmlText.substring(0, ind) + textCpb + " "+lblData.htmlText.substring(ind, lblData.htmlText.length);     
                    }
                    htmlModif=lblData.htmlText;                    
                    Clipboard.generalClipboard.clear(); 
                    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.copyFromGloss=false;
                }
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:TextArea id="lblData" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" 
                 htmlText="{dataGridListData.label}" 
                 wordWrap="true"
                 editable="true"
                 contentBackgroundColor="0xFFFFFF"
                 horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                 creationComplete="htmlModif=lblData.htmlText"
                 change="htmlModif=lblData.htmlText"
                 focusOut="lblData_focusOutHandler(event)"/>
</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Datagrid build

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgSuiviClini"
verticalGridLines="true"
horizontalGridLines="true"
horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
variableRowHeight="true"
dataProvider="{DP_LISTEREDVCLI}"
editable="true"
focusEnabled="true"
dropEnabled="true"
itemEditBegin="dgSuiviClini_itemEditBeginHandler(event)"
itemEditEnd="getCellInfo(event);"
itemFocusOut="getCellInfo(event)"
 width="100%" height="100%"
rowHeight="20">
<mx:columns>

<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="scRub2" headerText="{sNomCol2}" editable="true" 
width="{iNomCol2}"
id="dgc1" wordWrap="true" visible ="{bcol2Visible}"
itemRenderer="fr.ui.itemRenderer.MultilineHTMLRenderer"
itemEditor="fr.ui.itemRenderer.irCliHtmlEditor"
editorDataField="htmlModif"
editorUsesEnterKey="true" />
 </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

But in those cases the result is like that:
[image]

I'm very happy if you could hep me.

Thanks

Comment: When in edit mode; wouldn't you want the itemEditor separator to be visible?  I don't understand what you're asking and I think a screenshot of what you expect to see would help more than a screenshot of what you do see.  Without knowing your app I don't understand why that screenshot is wrong.

Comment: In edit mode, if itemeditor is taller than itemrender, separator appear, and in editing cell I'd like to disable separator because, it appear on itemeditor background. Horizontal separator mustn't appear in editing for editing cell

Comment: It looks like the separator (that white horizontal line going through the text in your screen shot) is being drawn on top of the itemEditor. So your solution won't fix that... Perhaps you might want to show more code or better yet, include a simple example app that we can play with (and thereby advise on a solution).

Comment: Since you know when edit mode starts / stops, why not hide / show the renderer then?

Comment: Your item renderer is not showing through your item editor, you have the same code in both it would seem as part of your updateDisplayList override. Remove the graphics part in your itemEditor and it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you explain about graphics part. Indeed, I comment  updateDisplayList function but problem is same.